# Minecraft; Drops of carrots

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Can you still obtain carrots from zombies in Minecraft 1.11.2? I have a world where I need carrots for potions. I have LITERALLY everything else. I can't find any villages, though. Know any good ways to get carrots? -- Thanks!

Comment: Definitely still possible. I will put this to the test in a minute, but if you need to find a village then use amidst, it generates a giant map of your world.

Comment: I'd rather ask what the heck is with lack of villages! They are not exactly uncommon. I have places on my map where I have three villages within view range. You should really explore some more to find them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to [Experimental Rocket's answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/303691/73976), The *chance* of a carrot dropping is very low.

[From the wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Drops#Rare_drops) (emphasis mine):

> Rare drops occur in addition to the common drops. **Unlike most common drops, they only occur if the monster is killed by a player.**
> [...]
>  Rare drops typically have a **2.5% chance of dropping, plus 1 percentage point per level of Looting** on the weapon used (up to a maximum of 5.5% with Looting III).

The annoying thing with *chance* is that it could happen at any time. I once got a carrot after 15 minutes of gameplay, and another time I didn't get one from a Zombie until I had already discovered 3 villages (after nearly 48hrs of gameplay), by which point it was redundant.

Comment: Okay. Very helpful! :) I appreciate your time.

Answer (score 1):

According to the patch notes on [this](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Zombie) page, no abilities were removed from the Zombies category, only the addition of the husk (latest zombie addition).

An image of the 1.11 patch notes can be seen below, as well as on the page linked above.

[image: 1.11 Patch notes]

Hope this helped. I did run some additional test's where I summoned zombie's and killed them with /kill but they only fropped flesh, which I guess is due to a summoned zombies NBT data.